# Having an issue with a problem my friend showed me. Can you help me please?

Tags: combinations

A college offers 2 introductory courses in history, 1 in Science, 2 in Math, 2 in Philosophy, and 4 in English. If a freshman takes one course in each area during her 1st semester, how many course selections are possible?

Comment: Well, I've tried to break it down the old fashioned way by counting, but it's been too long since I"e done problems like this.  I can't remember any formulas for this particular type of problem.

Comment: If you have 3 shirts and 2 pairs of pants, how many outfits can you make?

Comment: Is the answer 6?

Comment: $6$ is correct for this one, coming from $3 \times 2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  It is few enough to count by hand, which would be good to understand what is going on.  Let the courses be S, M1, M2, P1, P2, E1, E2, E3, E4 and you choose one of each letter.  For a start, ignore S and M:  how many choices are there for P and E?  For each P, you can choose how many E's?

Comment: For P and E, 8.  For each P, there would be 4 E's.  Correct?

Comment: That is correct.  Now for each combination of E and P, you have two choices for M.  The general principle is that independent choices multiply.

Comment: So that particular equation would be 8 times 8?

Comment: No, for each of the eight choices of P,E you have two choices of M, so $8 \times 2$ choices for P,E,M

Comment: Oh okay.  (P)4x(E)2x(M)2, right?

Comment: Therefore, the final equation would be 4x2x2x2x1, correct?